# Skeletal topological groupoid

Tags: ct.category-theory, topological-groups, groupoids

Let $G$ be a topological groupoid with the property that any two isomorphic objects are topologically indistinguishable in $\mathrm{Ob}(G)$. Does that imply that $G$ is equivalent to a skeletal topological groupoid (where equivalence is meant in the sense defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418208/topological-groupoids-and-equivariant-sheaves))?

Comment: Note: this question already occured in a previous version of the linked thread, but I decided to remove it and put it in a separate question, since this question hasn't been answered in the linked thread, and the linked thread already contained too many other questions (all of which where answered!).